# How to display an error message when the quantity for a product is more than 3 in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a product added through woocommerce for my client's website.

Now, I want to show "ADD TO CART" only if the product's qty is 3 or below. If the Qty is more than 3, then the "ADD TO CART" button should be disabled and another button called "CONTACT" should be enabled.(Or, it is fine if it displays some error message if the user choose more than 3 quantities).

Simply says, For Quantities 3 or below - we can add to cart
For Quantities more than 3 - display error msg (or) CONTACT button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'wc_add_to_cart_validation', 11, 3 ); 
function wc_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if ( $quantity > 3 ){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Only 3 or less quantities allowed, please contact us.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

this will check up quantity on add to cart validation.

code goes to your current active theme's functions.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is it possible for the "ADD TO CART" button to change to "CONTACT" when the quantity is more than 3?

Comment: How to use the above function for a particular product id?